# Is the topological space $ (X^{*},\sigma (X ^ {*}, X)) $ metrizable?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, isometry, dual-spaces

**Definition 1:** Let $X$ be a normed space. The operator 
\begin{align*}
    J_{X}\colon X&\to X^{**}\\
    x&\mapsto J_{X}(x)(x^{*})=x^{*}(x)
\end{align*}
is called *canonical lace* (or *canonical immersion*) of $X$ into $X^{**}. $

**Lemma 1:** Let $X$ be a normed space. Then the canonical immersion $J_{X}$ of $X$ into $X^{∗∗}$ is an isometric isomorphism.

**Definition 2:** Let $ (X, \Vert \cdot \Vert) $ be a normed space. The *weak-* topology*, denoted by $ \sigma (X ^{*}, X), $ is the smallest topology at $ X ^{*} $ that makes every element of $ \{J_ {X} (x) \mid x \in X \} \subseteq {X ^{**}}$ continuous.

Let
\begin{equation*}
    X=c_{00}=\{x=(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}}\mid \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, x_{n}=0, \forall n\geq N\}.
\end{equation*}

**Question:** Is the topological space $ (X^{*},\sigma (X ^ {*}, X)) $ metrizable?

Attempt: We know that $(c_{00},\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty})$ is a normed space, which is not Banach. A completion of $(c_{00},\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty})$ is
\begin{equation*}
    c_{0}=\left\{y=(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}}\ \middle|\ \lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}{x_{n}}=0\right\}
\end{equation*} 
that is, there is $J\colon c_{00}\to c_{0}$ linear such that $\Vert J(x)\Vert=\Vert x\Vert,\forall x\in c_{00}$ and $\overline{J(c_{00})}=c_{0}.$

Furthermore, we know that
\begin{equation*}
    X^{*}=c_{0}^{*}=l_{1}=\left\{z=(z_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}}\ \middle|\ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{z_{n}}<\infty\right\}.
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    l_{1}^{*}=l^{\infty}=\left\{w=(w_{n})\in\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}} \ \middle|\ \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{|w_{n}|\}<\infty \right\}.
\end{equation*}

I don't know if I can conclude what I want with the above.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is there a proposition that justifies what you said? I ask you why I don't know

Comment: Indeed I think it is not even first countable

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: It's well known in the case that $X$ is a Banach space, but here it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, the space turns out to be metrizable.
To see this, let $\delta_k \in c_{00}$ be the sequence which is one in the $k$-th entry and zero elsewhere.
Now, note that if $(\varphi_\alpha)_{\alpha}$ is a net in $X^\ast$ and $\varphi \in X^\ast$, then
$\varphi_\alpha \to \varphi$ in the weak-$\ast$ topology if and only if
$\varphi_\alpha (\delta_n) \to \varphi(\delta_n)$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.
This uses that every $x \in X$ is a finite linear combination of $\delta_n$'s.

Now, define
$$
  d (\varphi, \psi)
  := \sum_{n=1}^\infty
       \min \{ 2^{-n}, |\varphi(\delta_n) - \psi(\delta_n)| \}
  \quad \text{for} \quad
  \varphi,\psi \in X^\ast .
$$
It is not hard to see that this is a metric (change that each summand is a pseudo-metric) and that
$d(\varphi_\alpha, \varphi) \to 0$ if and only if $\varphi_\alpha(\delta_n) \to \varphi(\delta_n)$
for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

This shows that the topology you are interested in is induced by the metric $d$.

Comment: In other words, the weak-* topology here equals the subspace topology from the product topology on $\mathbb{K}^{\mathbb{N}}$, and the latter is well known to be metrizable.

Comment: I have a doubt. I found a proposition. I don't know if it's true. If the weak- * topology in X is metrizable, then $ X ^{*}$ (and, therefore, X) is of finite dimension. So I have doubts. Is the topological dual of $ c_{00} $ metrizable?

Comment: Another Doubt The metric d you defined earlier is effectively a metric, since in any metric space $(X, d)$ the function $ \min \{d (x, y), 1 \} $ is a metric. That's right?

Comment: @Darkmaster:For your second comment: Yes, exactly. For your first comment: Where did you find this proposition? Does it assume normed vector spaces or Banach spaces? The topological dual of $c_{00}$ is (as you noted) $\ell^1$, which is metrizable, and (as I showed) the weak-$\ast$ topology on $X^\ast$ **coming from** $c_{00}$ is also metrizable.

Comment: @Darkmaster The weak$^{\ast}$-topology on $X^{\ast}$ is metrisable if and only if the (algebraic) dimension of $X$ is (at most) countable.